# How to change File- New-C++ to Java in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I don't know why it change to C++ because I only need Java.

How can I change to Java?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try resetting app settings and then create a project of your preferred language choice.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after importing an empty git project. Android studio did not set the project to be a Java project.

I solved this with the following steps:

- create a new Java project with Android Studio
- copy the generated files to another folder
- clone the git repository into the, now empty, project folder
- copy the generated files back into the project folder

Though the response is late, I hope this will help others with a similar problem.